# Querying AWS DynamoDB to return lat and lon result within radius

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am fairly new to dynamodb and i have it setup with lambda and api gateway.

My dynamodb table looks like this.
[image]

Now i am simply querying the table with the following lambda function.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    /**
     * Debugging events
     * @type {[type]}
     */
    console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
    console.log("Context received:\n", JSON.stringify(context));

    /**
     * Important this needs to be your Dynamo DB table name
     * @type {String}
     */
    var tableName = "Tracker";
    var datetime = new Date().getTime().toString();

    var queryData = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "ConsistentRead": true,
        "KeyConditionExpression": "TrackIt = :val",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":val": {"S": event.tid}}
    };
    dynamoDB.query(queryData, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
        }else{
            context.done(null,data.Items);
        }
    });

};
```

Now what i want to do is query the table based on latitude and longitude values in a certain radius say 3 miles, now i know how to do this with mysql but i would really like to know where to start when trying to do this with dynamodb.

I cant really find any helpful tutorials online has anyone else done this or is doing this that could point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an expression such as:

```
var queryData = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "ConsistentRead": true,
        "KeyConditionExpression": "#latitude between :min and :max",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
            "#latitude": "latitude",
        },
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":min": [MIN_LATITUDE],
            ":max": [MAX_LATITUDE] 
        }
    };
```

For more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html

Comment: Hi @filipebarretto thats for your response i am just curious would you agree with the above answer that Dynamodb is not a good solution for this kind of setup, perhaps i should be using a RDS instead it is just so expensive.

Comment: I believe it's not just the query that should support this decision. Here is a link on when to use SQL or no SQL databases https://www.sitepoint.com/sql-vs-nosql-choose/. If you do choose RDS, the t2.micro instance is only about 15 dollars a month and you can use reserved instances to lower the cost. (If my query answer suited you, could you please upvote it?)

Comment: Hi @filipebarretto i have decided to go with Slim framework on EC2 for cost RDS is far to expensive and dont want to be caught out again with AWS thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that Dynamo is going to be a good solution if you will need to frequently support geospatial lookup use cases. You might consider database solutions which more directly support geospatial functionality.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your response would you suggest using a RDS db instead?

Comment: @user1503606 Perhaps. I know MySQL and Postgres RDS instances have geospatial functionalities. Not sure about other RDS instance types (MSSQL and Oracle).  I did find this DynamoDB geohashing library via Google which may actually give some options for doing location-based look-ups using Dynamo - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/09/05/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-geospatial-indexing/